# mongo db JS .map not working in GAE despite it working in localhost? or something else

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-app-engine, foreach

I have Node app with mongo db that works perfectly in localhost, but as I deploy it to Google App Engine one particular function of the app stops working. This function uses .map to get information from mongo db; fetching a value into javascript object based on the mongo generated _id field.

Questions are:

1. Is there a reason (perhaps environment) why this would not work in Google App Engine?
2. Is there a good alternative to .map? .forEach is the best?
3. Any other pointers where I could start troubleshooting from with something working in localhost and not deployed to GAE?

Answer (score 0):

1 and 3 - Can you explain how did you set your app? Can you check the logs and see what's going wrong? You can check this [community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine) on how to connect Node.js to Mongo db. My guess is that you missed installing some libraries that are on the localhost server but not once you deploy, but without further clarification I cannot answer. I will update if more info is provided.

2- `.forEach` execute a function for each element of one array but `.map` creates an array with the result of executing a function for each element, the difference is very subtle  . In general, `.forEach` is better if you are not going to change data in the original array (such as printing the value) and `.map` is better if you want to change it (converting to float for example).